# TCP Socket Programming in Python3: Recieving alternate message at Server Side

Tags: sockets, python-3.x, tcp

I coded server side and client side and I am using TCP connection.

Server Side:

```
import socket

def Main():
  host = '192.168.1.3'
  port = 5014

  s = socket.socket()
  s.bind((host,port))
  s.listen(1)
  c,addr = s.accept()

  while True:
    if c.recv(1024).decode('UTF_8') == 'Q':
        print('Terminating Connection...')
        c.close()
        s.close()
        break;
    else:
        print(c.recv(1024).decode('UTF_8'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  Main()
```

Client Side:

```
import socket

def Main():
  host = '192.168.1.3'
  port = 5014

  c = socket.socket()
  c.connect((host,port))

  data = ''
  while True:
    if data == 'Q':
        break;
    else:
        data = input('->')
        c.send(data.encode('UTF_8'))

  print('Terminating Connection...')
  c.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  Main()
```

It seems everything is correct, but while running , when I am giving input at client side, message is printing up only alternatively.

Example:
Client Side Input:

```
->hello1
->hello2
->hello3
->hello4
->Q
Terminating Connection...
```

Server Side Output:

```
hello2
hello4
Terminating Connection...
```

I am not getting why hello1 and hello3 are not getting printed.
Please help. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Read line 1... it's not Q, so read line 2 and print it.  What happened to line 1?

Comment: you may have a point :) I confirm: store recv in a temp variable and it works perfectly.

Comment: Yes, You are right @MattTimmermans. How can I be so stupid. Now I saved the recv in a variable and it is working fine. Thank You very much.